# NextJS: use a custom server (NestJS) to render specific pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, nestjs

I'm trying to use NestJS as a [custom server](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-server) for NextJS as described in [this article](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/render-next-js-with-nestjs-did-i-just-made-next-js-better-aa294d8d2c67), a simplified version would look like this:

```js
@Controller('/')
export class ViewController {
  @Get('*')
  async static(@Req() req: Request, @Res() res: Response) {
    // This returns a Next() app as described in https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-server
    const server = this.viewService.getNextServer();
    const handle = server.getRequestHandler();
    handle(req, res);
  }
}
```

This works fine as long as I register the handler for any route (i.e. `@Get('*')`). E.g. when I visit `/home` then `pages/home.tsx` is rendered.

However, due to [another issue](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/6866) I want to register it only for specific pages, e.g. `@Get('/home')`. In that case, I get an empty 404 page from Next (no content on the page, 404 in title). Console shows:

```
event - build page: /next/dist/pages/_error
wait  - compiling...
event - compiled successfully
```

NestJS uses express in the background, so I imagine this translates to something like `server.get('/home', handle);`. Same issue if I try to use a regex e.g. `@Get(/^\/(?!graphql).*/)`. Same issue if I try `@Controller('/home')` and `@Get('*')`.

Looking for some solution to make a Nest app serve specific Next pages. I know about [nest-next](https://github.com/kyle-mccarthy/nest-next) but I'd prefer just setting up a plain controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using the `render` method from Next as also explained in [this article](https://csaba-apagyi.medium.com/nestjs-react-next-js-in-one-mvc-repo-for-rapid-prototyping-faed42a194ca):

```js
@Controller('/')
export class ViewController {
  @Get('home')
  public async showHome(@Req() req: Request, @Res() res: Response) {
    const parsedUrl = parse(req.url, true);
    // This returns a Next() app as described in https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-server
    const server = this.viewService.getNextServer();
    await server.render(req, res, parsedUrl.pathname, parsedUrl.query);
  }
}
```